# Swift selector is not strict?

Tags: swift, selector

When I use NSTimer in swift, it seem that swift doesn't check method signature that is no mater what selector I passed `called` or `called:` swift can perform my selector correctly. Does Apple support this feature officially so I can use this feature to ignore argument safely?

Answer (score 3):

No, unlike the Objective-C compiler the Swift compiler does not currently verify selector names. You may want to file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com but I believe this is a known enhancement request.

(Information above current as of Swift 2.0)